# Select only one radio button in a row with telerik radgrid

Tags: wpf, telerik, radio-button, radgrid

I have 2 radio button columns in telerik radgridview, I want to have selected only one radio button in a row How to do this ?

Comment: WPF package doesn't have a radgrid control, it has a gridview control. Are you talking about WPF, or asp.net AJAX controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user1834059 said, use the `GroupName` property. The `GroupName` should be unique for each row, so use your DataKey or any other dataItem value that would be unique for each row (some id).

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" >
        <MasterTableView 
                        DataKeyNames="myDataKey">
            <Columns>

                ...Your columns...

                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="radioButton1" runat="server"
                                        Text="Your text"
                                        GroupName='{Binding myDataKey}' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="radioButton2" runat="server"
                                        Text="Your text"
                                        GroupName='{Binding myDataKey}' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: I think this helpful, but how can i do this in WPF am not sure there exists a Eval property in wpf

Comment: You are right, the equivalent for WPF is `{Binding myDataKey}`